# How does Laravel's ORM specify the sorted values for the data?

Tags: mysql, laravel-5, eloquent

E.g:
There is a field in the table called name,
Name contains some user names, for example:

```
| name |
---------
| Asal |
| Codaya |
| Ostily |
| Queen |
| Qta |
| Zoo |
```

What do you want to achieve, for example, I am passing a value now, for example, passing Q, then the returned data, that is, all the first letters Q are in front, like this:

```
| name |
-------------
| Queen |
| Qta |
| Asal |
| Codaya |
| Ostily |
| Zoo |
```

If you pass in a Z, it becomes like this:

```
| name |
------------
| Zoo |
| Asal |
| Codaya |
| Ostily |
| Queen |
| Qta |
```

How is this requirement implemented in mysql?

Comment: What's the purpose of sorting results by a character/string do you want to achieve? if it's just for auto-completing a user input in an HTML input, then I recommend using jqueryui autocomplete, pass your data to it, and it will do the job. https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Comment: Not only the front-end sorting, I need to deal with it in the backend, because there are a lot of features for page turning, because there are only 20 data that I pass to the front end every time I page, so I need this function.

Answer (score 0):

I think your best option would be this in SQL:

```
SELECT 
    name
FROM
    user
ORDER BY 
CASE
    WHEN name LIKE 'E%' THEN 1
    ELSE 2
END
```

If you are using Doctrine as ORM, I believe `CASE` is not supported natively in `ORDER BY` (in DQL), so you would have to go with raw SQL, I guess.